# Download XML and parse it with ReadAsAsync

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to download XML document and parse it with the following piece of code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"https://domain.com/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

    var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key1", "value1"),
    };

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
        @"/", new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));

    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SomeClass>();
}
```

ReadAsAsync method raises an exception:

> The encoding in the declaration 'windows-1251' does not
>   match the encoding of the document 'utf-8'.

Passing XML formatting options like the following

```
var xml_formatter = new XmlMediaTypeFormatter();

xml_formatter.SupportedEncodings.Add(
    Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));

var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SomeClass>(
    new[] { xml_formatter });
```

raises another exception:

> XML encoding not supported.

Encodings of the content and the XML document are windows-1251.
Is this a bug or limitation of ReadAsAsync method?